# OCaml: how to determine type of the function argument?

Tags: types, ocaml, matching

I learned that functions accepting arbitrary types could be created, like these:

```
let f x = x;;

let f x = ();;

let f (x : 'a) = ();;
```

But I could not find a way to utilize type information inside function, like this:

```
let print_is = function
    | (x : int) -> print_int x
    | (s : string) -> print_string s
    | _ -> print_string "***";;
```

Is it really impossible at all, and if so - what is the underlying idea of such restriction? Or I just failed to google properly?

Comment: One of the best advantage of OCaml is that you don't need to explicitly care about `type`.

Comment: Ah... well, but now I only need to discover how to use it :D

Comment: If you want to handle values that are either of one type or another, OCaml does this very well. It's called variants. So you can do things like `type footwear = Shoe of shoe_size | Sock`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml does not keep type information at run-time: in order to write the program you suggest, one would need to match on the *type* of `x`, thus one would need a value that represents the type of `x` in order to pattern-match on it.

I see two ways to further reply to your question:

- inspecting the type of a parameter and building a value that represents the said type is a research problem that is still actively investigated: it is hard to perform these operations in a type-safe way that furthermore does not break abstraction. Grégoire Henry is currently doing that and seems to be sharing his work on https://github.com/c-cube/ocaml-ty
- If you're looking for a way to print an arbitrary value, the natural way in OCaml would be to directly use the "right" function to print the type you want, as *there is no universal printer in OCaml*. That being said, there are extra libraries such as [deriving](https://github.com/jaked/deriving) that can generate automatic printers for your type definitions.

Comment: > OCaml does not keep type information at run-time

Ah, at last I get the sense of the phrase. Then it is clearly really impossible, like in C. Well, all right, it is not crucial problem.

Comment: "there is no universal printer in OCaml" Well, there *are* printing functions that work on any value of any type, using reflection. However, it cannot distinguish between values of different types that are represented the same at runtime. But it still goes pretty far, and recursively prints the structure of composite types correctly.

Comment: Absolutely, meaning that the function would just see a pointer to a block with tag 0, and would be unable to understand whether this is the tag that means "Cons" as in:

```
type 'a list = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a list
```

or something else from another type.